# ODE with a control

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to understand the solution of this ODE.
Let $t \in [0,2]$,
$$\begin{cases}
\dot x =  ux\\
x(0) = 1 \\
x(2) = 3^6 \\
|u|  \le 1 
\end{cases}
$$

On the notes I'm reading, they say that $0 \leq \dot x = ux \leq 3x$ and $x(0)=1$  imply that $0 \leq x(t) \leq e^{3t}$.
How can I come to this conclusion?
I have no idea why $\dot x \ge 0$.

Thank you!

Comment: Gronwall's inequality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\dot{x} \ge 0$ then $x(t) \ge x(0)$.

If $\dot{x} -3x \le 0$, then ${d \over dt } e^{-3t}x \le 0$ and so $e^{-3t}x(t) \le x(0)$.

So, in fact $ 1 \le x(t) \le e^{3t}$ for $t \in [0,2]$.

Comment: Why is $\dot x \ge 0$?

Comment: That was part of your question???

Comment: Yes, I am not able to prove it though

Comment: Of course, if $u =-1$ then $\dot{x} = -x$. and so $\dot{x}(0) = -1$.